# Why is the Firefox debugger not showing full source code?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

I am trying to debug a web page in Firefox v42.0 Windows 10, where that web page goes through a proxy server and has code injected into it inline via `<script>...</script>` (not including a separate .js file) by the proxy server. When I right-click View Page Source, I see the original page plus the code I expect to see injected (and which is actually running). I also see the injected content in the DOM view of the Inspector tab. And it is also visible in the Network Tab in the Response section. However, when I view the same page in the debugger, the injected code is not visible, as if the page were not running through the proxy server.

Furthermore, if I insert a `debugger;` statement in the injected code, I do hit the breakpoint, but in the Firefox debugger tab it tells me I'm on line 550 of a file with only 173 lines in it according to Firefox. So I can not step through the code.

When I do the same thing in Chrome, I see what I'm expecting, which is the injected code in my page, and I am able to debug this code without problem.

I have cleared my cache to no effect. I looked at the Network tab and everything looks as expected there.

How and why is Firefox not showing me the actual page in the debugger tab (matching what's in View Source or the DOM view), and not letting me step through the injected code?

Answer (score 22):

There are a few bugs in Firefox that can cause this that I've encountered myself:

- A local caching issue which can be solved by first closing the dev tools window, hard-reloading the page (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + R), then opening the debugger again.
- <del>Trying to debug a tab in a container, but the source is showing the page as it would be outside a container. See bug [1375036](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1375036)).</del> This particular case should now be fixed.
- Similar to the previous point, the debugger source showing you a slighty/completely different document to the one that's actually currently rendered by the browser. This is due to the fact that the debugger does not have access to the original markup & inline script the browser used to render the current page! Apparently designed that way to be memory efficient, but seems to ignore the fact that a developer *wants* to use the memory for storing the source, because they want the actual source. See bugs such as [1060732](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1060732), [1149835](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1149835), and [1472581](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1472581).

If this is happening to you try debugging in the default/no container, or just do it in Chrome . If you can't debug in another browser, at least **try a fresh profile before** you "refresh" (nuke) Firefox as others suggest. You can do this from the `about:profiles` page (address must be typed manually or bookmarked), or by opening Firefox with the `-P` flag and creating a new one. To use those flags, run `firefox -P --no-remote` from a *nix/Mac terminal or `C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe -P --no-remote` from the Windows Run dialogue; the `--no-remote` flag is not required but allows you to run the new profile alongside your main one, and disregard links clicked in other programs.

Comment: For me, problem was "caching". Closing the debugger, refreshing (ctrl-shift-R) and reopenning the debugger did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

The below worked for me

1. Copy url from address bar and close the tab.
2. Open the url in private mode, the debugger shows the source.
3. Close private window and open in default mode, the debugger shows the source now.

Comment: I can't believe something like that could work.

Answer (score 8):

Try to refresh Firefox:

"Refresh Firefox

1. Click the menu button and then click help.
2. From the Help menu choose Troubleshooting Information.
3. Click the Refresh Firefox button in the upper-right corner of the Troubleshooting Information page.
4. To continue, click Refresh Firefox in the confirmation window that opens.
5. Firefox will close to refresh itself. When finished, a window will list your imported information. Click Finish and Firefox will open."

Check this for more information:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

I had the same problem. I solved it following these instructions.

Comment: I was a bit desperate, tried it and then spent minutes to re-setup the Firefox. And... it did not help with my debugging problem. I don't know why they call it "Refresh" and not "Reset" instead. Firefox in general is much buggier with dev tools and JavaScript than Chrome. :-(

Comment: I was a bit skeptical, but actually this worked for me after a similar problem occurred in Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit) on Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: You should warn people about how heavy-handed this solution is.

Comment: Refreshing Firefox fixed the problem, however within a couple of minutes I had the same issue. As it has turned out, unchecking the `disable cache` on the network tab solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but this was due to the index page redirecting to a subdirectory.  The subdirectory contained the index.html with the javascript include files.  The src files only got displayed only when an error occurred.  To get around this, I cleared all my cache and I went directly to the subdirectory.